# How to resize one image with PIL in 1ms?

Tags: python, image

I want to resize image in python with PIL.
But I find it needs 70 ms by PIL.
the original image is 1080*1920, I want to change it to 500*500.
Can you tell me how to quickly make this change?

Here is my code

```
 from PIL import Image

 img = Image.open('/your iamge path/image.jpg')
 import time
 start=time.clock()
 img = img.resize((500, 500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
 end =time.clock()
 print end-start
```

Comment: That's very broad. I recommend adding a lot more info about your benchmark, needs and the whole-task as this touches a lot of complex stuff, including latency vs. bandwidth and much more.

Comment: It maybe clearly .

Comment: So you don't want help from more experienced users i guess?

Comment: no no, OK I will make it more detail.

Comment: You're not going to resize an image that is 1080x1920 in 1ms using Python alone. Python is an interpreted language. Set realistic goals, or use a different language that isn't interpreted. (And no, we cannot recommend what you should use instead - see the [help/on-topic] regarding recommendations for tools or libraries.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a 1920*1080 pixel image you got for usual 1920*1080*3 integers to work with. The most simple algorithm for resizing would be stretching each individual pixel or dropping pixels.

So, to stretch the picture you'd still need to access pretty much every pixel, leaving you with more than a million accesses, and a further million for the resulting picture (depending on the resize resolution maybe more, maybe less).

Reaching 1 milisecond would be seriously fast, even if you operate close to the hardware. Python generally is quite a bit slower than other programming languages, as speed isn't its main concern.

So your best bet would be to look for an all C library doing that job and wrapping it for python.

---

Edit:

Okay, the library is really close indeed.

Just resize the picture with the filter Image.NEAREST. E.g.:

```
img = Image.open("the picture")
w = 500
h = 500

img = img.resize((w,h),Image.NEAREST)
```

It's obviously gonna be ugly if you stretch the picture to much (as the filtering mechanism is the most primitive), but it's fast: From 1920*1080 to 500*500 it took me 2.4 ms

Comment: Internally PIL and every other good python-lib will do it in C/C++. The python-argument does not hold here.

Comment: can you give me some advice for C library ?

Comment: @Beili: No. A library recommendation is inappropriate here. Do your own research.

Comment: Ok I will do my research\

Comment: @Sudix, it needs 30ms in my test.

Comment: If you're using the timeit module, be aware that it doesn't automatically calculate the average. If you're picking a low number to test it on, the CPU needing some time to turn to its single-core-turbo-mode also factors in (on that note, you'd probably profit from multithreading). Finally, for my test I factored out the time necessary to import library and picture.

Answer (score -1):

I've done some extensive work in this area. Long story short, Python and PIL won't be fast enough to do this in 1ms. Try using Go along with the fantastic Govips library https://github.com/davidbyttow/govips

Example from https://github.com/davidbyttow/govips/blob/master/examples/resize/resize.go:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/davidbyttow/govips"
)

func run(inputFile, outputFile string) error {
    in, err := govips.NewImageFromFile(inputFile,
        govips.NewOptions().SetInt("access", int(govips.AccessSequential)))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    interp, err := govips.NewInterpolator("nohalo")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    out := in.ResizeEx(0.2, govips.NewOptions().SetInterpolator("interpolate", interp))

    out.WriteToFile(outputFile, nil)

    return nil
}

var (
    flagIn  = flag.String("in", "", "file to load")
    flagOut = flag.String("out", "", "file to write out")
)

func main() {
    flag.Usage = func() {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "resize -in input_file -out output_file")
    }
    flag.Parse()

    govips.Startup(nil)
    defer govips.Shutdown()

    err := run(*flagIn, *flagOut)
    if err != nil {
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give an example

Comment: This is a comment to the question, not an answer. Answers are self-sustaining, with the relevant information here. Off-site links should only be additional resources, but the answer should still be useful if that off-site location is unavailable. This answer does not meet those standards.

Answer (score -3):

Using python-resize-image library:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('/your iamge path/image.jpg') # image extension *.png,*.jpg
new_width  = 500
new_height = 500
img = img.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save('output image name.png') # format may what u want ,*.png,*jpg,*.gif
```

Comment: but it needs 70ms

Comment: check out this link https://blog.uploadcare.com/the-fastest-production-ready-image-resize-out-there-part-0-7c974d520ad9

Comment: the blog url is not correct

Comment: here you go: goo.gl/xNBzEL